Oddly large coefficients in meta-regression with correlated and hierarchical effects
I am performing meta-regression to investigate the effect of participant characteristics and study characteristics on the incident rate ratio (IRR) estimates. I have data from 10 studies, each contributed multiple effect estimates for different age group, sex, and risk window lengths. Description of my data could be found HERE.
I used random-effect meta-regression with robust variance estimation (RVE) and small sample correction (package metafor & clubSandwich). I chose correlated and hierarchical effects as the working model for RVE. The outcome variable was the log of the IRR.
As the explanatory variables varied both within and between study, I used the study mean and study-mean-centered values of those variables to estimate both between-study and within-study effects, as recommended by Yaremych (2023)
The variable "proportion of male" (prop_male_guess) had 5 levels: 0%, <45%, 45%-55%, >55%, 100%. The table below shows the distribution of each level in my data, the diagonal cells are the number of studies (effect sizes) with that level:

Because the level "<45%" only occurred in 1 study, I merged it with level "45-55" -> new level "roughly equal".
When I fit the model with "proportion of male" as the predictor, the intercept and coefficients got exceptionally large:
# Load data and fit the model
urlfile=
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trangtph/Meta_Regression/main/example_data.csv"
mydata <- read_csv(url(urlfile))

# constant sampling correlation working model
rho_const <- 0.7
V <- vcalc(var, cluster = study_id, obs = effect_id, data = mydata, 
             rho = rho_const)

# Model with group mean centering
model_sex <- 
  rma.mv(log_effect ~ 1 + prop_male_merge_roughly.equal.c + 
           prop_male_merge_.55.c  + prop_male_merge_100.c +
           prop_male_merge_roughly.equal_m  + prop_male_merge_.55_m + 
           prop_male_merge_100_m, V = V, 
           random = ~ 1 | study_id / effect_id,
           data = mydata, sparse = TRUE)

model_sex_robust <- robust(model_sex, cluster=study_id, 
                            clubSandwich=TRUE)

This is the model output:
Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 122; method: REML)

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed              factor 
sigma^2.1  0.1044  0.3231     10     no            study_id 
sigma^2.2  0.3511  0.5925    122     no  study_id/effect_id 

Test of Moderators (coefficients 2:7):¹
F(df1 = 6, df2 = 0) = 0.0000, p-val = NA


The within-study effects (covariates end with ".c") are fine but the intercept and the between-study effects (covariates end with "_m") are exceptionally large (The intercept of 13.4 would translate into an impossible IRR of 660003).
My question is: How could I explain the strange behavior of my model?. One of my guesses is the correlation between the levels: "<45", "45-55" ">55" never occurred together in a study. But I am not sure.
A side question: The degrees of freedom from my model are quite low. As in Tipton (2015), p-values with DF <4 should not be trusted. So is there any way to produce reliable standard errors and p-values in RVE?
Any suggestion is appreciated!

I notice that when I collapsed the level "<45%" to the reference level "0%" then the model coefficients became normal again. So what does this imply?

It is b etter to add new info as an edit to the post, rather than as a comment, so please do so. Comments on this site are ephemeral, easy to overlook, and can be deleted!
